# Filtering MSM articles by site

Tags: multi-site-manager

I've setup a page that shows news from four different sites that are all within the same MSM (Multi site manager) build, the page is working great but I want to be able to filter by site. I basically want the following:

News listing (domain.com/all-news)
- news from all sites

News listing filtered (domain.com/all-news/site1)
- news from one site

Or alternatively it would be great to have the filters working with ajax

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could use a combination of conditionals, the site= parameter, and  a segment variable.

Comment: Thanks Michael, seems I have a total mind blank, {exp:channel:entries {if segment_1 == "site1"}site="site1"{/if}{if segment_1 == "site2"}site="site2"{/if}}

Comment: I was thinking more {exp:channel:entries site="{segment_2}"} etc...then build links that create that URL structure to trigger the filtering.